# What are the decimal and grouping marks in modern Latin?

Tags: contemporary-latin, orthography, numbers

To write non-integer numbers in the decimal system (without fractions), one needs a decimal mark.
In English one uses the decimal point, but in many other languages one uses a comma instead.
Wikipedia has a [whole article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark) about different decimal marks and where each type is used.

When writing large numbers, it is useful to group digits, typically in groups of three.
Conventions vary again:
Some would write a million as 1,000,000, some as 1.000.000, others as 1 000 000, and also 1'000'000 is in use.

The decimal and grouping marks typically depend on language.
**What are these marks for contemporary Latin?**
Is there any uniform practice or guideline, or is it inconsistent?

Comment: It's consistent with the Latin writer's native language.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Sounds likely. That would mean that Latin doesn't have its own convention.

Comment: Also note that Vicipaedia uses spaces in the place of a mark, but sometimes, there are exceptions. See either it's own Vicipaedia page or the image celebrating what I would translate as "100 000 of the pages."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contemporary Latin does not have a single body issuing punctuation guidelines. Therefore, what's used is typically defined by the writer's own country's conventions.

However, a large number (no pun intended) of modern Latin writers use Roman numerals. Ephemeris is a good example of both principles. Some articles ([like this one](http://ephemeris.alcuinus.net/scientiae.php)) use 9.000 for the American 9,000, but others ([like this other one](http://ephemeris.alcuinus.net/medicina.php)) uses only Roman numerals.

I've found that with really large numbers Arabic numerals are used instead of Roman ones, because writing 10<sup>10</sup> in Roman numerals isn't that easy.

Comment: Thanks! This satisfies my curiosity and confirms my suspicion. If someone finds a guideline (perhaps the Vatican has one, for example?), that would make a good additional answer.